# How to add a javascript button to PDF that saves data to a (png) file?

Tags: javascript, pdf, save, access-control

I create PDF figures with python+matplotlib and I can add a javascript alert box that shows the data from the figure when the PDF is opened.

I want to change the behavior in such a way that there is a button in the PDF. You might have seen "print" buttons in some forms. Pressing this button would ask the user the filename and save a hardcoded string to that file. Also another button could save the PDF as PNG (that can be hardcoded also).

The problem I have are privileges. The PDF-javascript-api says that silent file access is forbidden, but if a user initiates the save then it is allowed (e.g. with a standard save dialog).

However I cannot get the save dialog method to work. Adobe's `doc.saveAs()` without the arguments does not open save dialog, but complains about insufficient privileges.

I want the solution to be as portable as possible. Everything should be embedded into the PDF (one file).

**EDIT:**

Just found a similar but completely different approach: you can put attachments into PDFs that are like buttons and can be saved to disk:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117792/listings-copy-to-clipboard-feature

This is the current code that I have:

```
var nRslt = app.alert({cMsg: "save data?", nType: 3});
app.alert({cMsg: nRslt});
if (nRslt==4){
this.saveAs();
}
```

The button is in a form and if the result is 'OK' (nType = 4) the save dialog should be opened. This produces

```
NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method.
Doc.saveAs:4:Doc undefined:Open
```

The goal is to move the button to the document from the alert box and modify the content what is saved. But now the security settings are giving me a hard time.

Comment: The Acrobat JavaScript method is named saveAs() (note the capital A)

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks, I fixed the typo.

Comment: OK; so, it was a typo in the question, and not in the actual script…

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes, compiler complains about privileges, not on unknown functions. So I'd guess it finds the function but just cannot use it.

Comment: Could you show the code for the button?

Comment: @MaxWyss I added the current code to the question.

Comment: see answer; an answer allows for better formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provides the reason why the error gets thrown.

The `doc.saveAs()` method *REQUIRES* a valid path as argument. And, in order to work from a button, it requires higher privileges, which means that you'd have to create an application-level script, which has to be installed wherever the document should be used.

But there is another way, which does work:

```
if (app.alert({cMsg: "save data?", nType: 3}) == 4){
app.execMenuItem("SaveAs") ;
}
```

And with that, the Save File dialog opens.